# Mouse scroll wheel with selenium webdriver, on element without scrollbar?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to drive part of a web map akin to Google Maps, where zoom in/out is done by scrolling while moused over. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
someElement.scroll(-50)
```

The closest methods I saw in the documentation were `click` and `send_keys`, but neither of those do scrolling. I've also tried sending scrolls to the page via Javascript, e.g. `driver.execute_script("scroll(0,-50)")` This doesn't seem to do anything though.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To reproduce/test a mouse wheel, you'll have to emit the `mouseover`, `mousemove` and `wheel` events to the top element with a script injection.

Here's a working example with Google Map:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

def wheel_element(element, deltaY = 120, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0):
  error = element._parent.execute_script("""
    var element = arguments[0];
    var deltaY = arguments[1];
    var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var clientX = box.left + (arguments[2] || box.width / 2);
    var clientY = box.top + (arguments[3] || box.height / 2);
    var target = element.ownerDocument.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);

    for (var e = target; e; e = e.parentElement) {
      if (e === element) {
        target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));
        target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));
        target.dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent('wheel',     {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY, deltaY: deltaY}));
        return;
      }
    }    
    return "Element is not interactable";
    """, element, deltaY, offsetX, offsetY)
  if error:
    raise WebDriverException(error)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars --disable-extensions --window-size=1366,768")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/maps")

# get element
elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#scene > div.widget-scene > canvas")

# zoom in with mouse wheel
wheel_element(elm, -120)

# zoom out with mouse wheel
wheel_element(elm, 120)
```

As an alternative you could send the zoom shortucts which are +/- with Google map:

```py
# get element
elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#scene > div.widget-scene > canvas")

# zoom in with shortcut
elm.send_keys("+")

# zoom out with shortcut
elm.send_keys("-")
```

Comment: That does exactly what I was looking for! Thank you kindly. :)

(Admittedly, I did have to edit the css selector to `"#scene > .canvas-container canvas"`, but that's no biggie)

Comment: How to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

On google map, there is a zoom in/out button. You can use it instead of mouse scroll.

//To click on zoom in

```
driver.find_element_by_id('widget-zoom-in').click()
```

//To click on zoom out

```
driver.find_element_by_id('widget-zoom-out').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Florents great answer could be improved a tiny bit would by outsourcing the JS snippet into a separate file and wrap it into the old-style JS module format with readable parameter names.

A file called e.g. `simulate_wheel.js` with:

```js
/* global arguments */
(function (element, deltaY, offsetX, offsetY) {
    var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var clientX = box.left + (offsetX || box.width / 2);
    var clientY = box.top + (offsetY || box.height / 2);
    var target = element.ownerDocument.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);

    for (var e = target; e; e = e.parentElement) {
        if (e === element) {
            target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mouseover", {
                view: window,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                clientX: clientX,
                clientY: clientY
            }));
            target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
                view: window,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                clientX: clientX,
                clientY: clientY
            }));
            target.dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent("wheel", {
                view: window,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                clientX: clientX,
                clientY: clientY,
                deltaY: deltaY
            }));
            return "";
        }
    }
    return "Element is not interactable";
}).apply(null, arguments);
```

Which then can be read and used the following

```py
# Load it using the module loader, the module in this example is called "helper_js"
# Alternatively, simple read functions could be used
import pkgutil
wheel_js = pkgutil.get_data("helper_js", "simulate_wheel.js").decode("utf8")

def simulate_wheel(element, deltaY=120, offsetX=0, offsetY=0):
    error = element._parent.execute_script(wheel_js, element, deltaY, offsetX, offsetY)
    if error:
        raise WebDriverException(error)
```

This is [similar to how it's down inside the Selenium bindings for Python](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#L43).

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with PyRobot class,first focus on the points on which you want to perform zoom in/out and then use PyRobot class to perform zoom in/out operation via keyboard keys.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: P.S. This is for using Chrome version 107.0.5304.88 and Selenium version 4.6.0 (latest as of this post).

I tried so many things and none of them worked.. so many. I'm not sure if this is a version issue with Selenium or Python, but it was a real pain and documentation wasn't helpful.

Then I stumbled upon someone writing for Selenium in C# and their solution was slightly different. Adjusted for Python, this worked for me:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '25%'")
```

Good luck! Hope this helps someone else out.