# how to submit mouse scroll event by webdriver in python selenium in google store review window

Tags: javascript, selenium, scroll, mouse

mouse scroll event can be submit by selenium using this example

[Mouse scroll wheel with selenium webdriver, on element without scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274852/mouse-scroll-wheel-with-selenium-webdriver-on-element-without-scrollbar)

or using the java script
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

but when dealing with google maps review result window 
Ex.Statue of Liberty National Monument google place review

https://www.google.com.tw/maps/place/%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1%E5%A5%B3%E7%A5%9E%E5%83%8F/@40.6892494,-74.0466891,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m7!3m6!1s0x89c25090129c363d:0x40c6a5770d25022b!8m2!3d40.6892494!4d-74.0445004!9m1!1b1

the mouse scroll event can't be passed, seems this web page block the wheel event 
any idea?

Comment: The map is  a canvas