# How to perform Mouse Wheel scrolling over HTML5 Canvas in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas, mousewheel

I am working on a GWT Application (similar to Paint). In this, I have an HTML5 Canvas in which there is a functionality that scrolling a mousewheel up and down will zoom in and out of the canvas.

I have searched a lot but didn't find a workaround to fix this issue. Here's what  did:

```
int PosX = 0;
int PosY = 10;
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
String script = "document.getElementById('frontCanvas').scrollBy("
                                + PosX + "," + PosY + ")";
executor.executeScript(script); 

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.javaScriptThrowsNoExceptions(script));
```

Now, this above code is working for another Angular application in which I am scrolling up and down a div element (which has a scrollbar) but it is not working on my canvas (which doesn't have a scrollbar) in the GWT application.

I am using Selenium 3.14.0 and run this code on the Chrome browser.
Can anyone suggest what can be done to fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you calling `scrollBy` event on html element instead of calling it on `window` directly? It will only work if parent of `canvas` element has fixed height and width.

Comment: @DipenShah calling window directly isn't working in my case

Comment: Then I would suggest to go from parent to parent and find the parent whose width and height is smaller than `canvas` element it self. I guess that is the only way, to make it work.

Comment: @DipenShah, I'm not sure if this code can be used to achieve the desired objective.

Comment: Was just for demonstration of what I said earlier, but NVM.

Answer (score 6):

### [HTML5 Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

The HTML  element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via JavaScript. The  element is only a container for graphics. You must use JavaScript to actually draw the graphics. Canvas has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and adding images.

In general, to `scroll` the *mousewheel* *up* and *down* we could have opted for the [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Class. But as per [Automated Testing of HTML5 Canvas Applications with Selenium WebDriver](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/) it seems this API is not that reliable.  In Firefox, every `mouse down`, `mouse up`, or `mouse click` happens at the center of the element.  So the code above produces a `mouse move` event to the provided (**x**,**y**), then a `mouse move` event to the center of the Canvas, then a `mouse down`, `mouse up`, and `click` all at the center of the Canvas.  That may be fine for a button, but is unworkable for a **Canvas**, where you want to be able to `hover`, `click`, etc. at a specific location.  The situation is even worse in Safari, where it just produces an exception indicating that mouse move events aren't supported.  Chrome, meanwhile, works fine.

### Alternative

An work around would be to use the [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) Interface manually dispatching synthesized mouse events using JavaScript.

Taking a leaf out of @FlorentB.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274852/mouse-scroll-wheel-with-selenium-webdriver-on-element-without-scrollbar/47287595#47287595), to *scroll* a *mousewheel* **up** and **down**, you can emit the *mouseover*, *mousemove* and *wheel* **events** to the top element with a script injection and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  package demo;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class Canvas {

      static WebDriver driver;
      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
          driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/maps");
          WebElement elm = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#scene > div.widget-scene > canvas")));
          // Mouse wheel UP or Zoom In 
          wheel_element(elm, -500, 0, 0);
          System.out.println("Mouse wheel UP or Zoom In through Wheel achieved !!!");
          // Mouse wheel DOWN or Zoom Out 
          wheel_element(elm, 120, 0, 0);
          System.out.println("Mouse wheel DOWN or Zoom Out through Wheel achieved !!!");
          System.out.println("Mouse Scroll through Wheel achieved !!!");
      }

      public static void wheel_element(WebElement element, int deltaY, int offsetX, int offsetY)
      {
          try{
                String script = "var element = arguments[0];"
                  +"var deltaY = arguments[1];"
                  +"var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();"
                  +"var clientX = box.left + (arguments[2] || box.width / 2);"
                  +"var clientY = box.top + (arguments[3] || box.height / 2);"
                  +"var target = element.ownerDocument.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);"
                  +"for (var e = target; e; e = e.parentElement) {"
                    +"if (e === element) {"
                  +"target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));"
                  +"target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));"
                  +"target.dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent('wheel',     {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY, deltaY: deltaY}));"
                  +"return;"
                    +"}"
                  +"}";  

                WebElement parent = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].parentNode;", element);
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, parent, deltaY, offsetX, offsetY);
              }catch(WebDriverException e)
              {
              System.out.println("Exception caught in Catch block");
              }
      }

  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Mouse wheel UP or Zoom In through Wheel achieved !!!
  Mouse wheel DOWN or Zoom Out through Wheel achieved !!!
  Mouse Scroll through Wheel achieved !!!
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to find the coordinates of the buttons on a canvas, and click on them after using Java and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918530/how-to-find-the-coordinates-of-the-buttons-on-a-canvas-and-click-on-them-after/59923053#59923053)

Comment: I tried this method but it doesn't do anything in the canvas of the application in which I am working.

Answer (score 0):

This will scroll specific in the current page using JS

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
executor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(" + start + "," + end + ")");
```

else you can Scroll until a WebElement is found example:

```
WebElement x;
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
getJs().executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", x);
```

Thanks,