# How to check where is clicked in canvas(HTML) using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, canvas, coordinates

I have a canvas inside a window. The window is full screen, but the canvas is not the full size. I want to click a specific position in canvas so I use bellow:
`Actions action = new Actions(driver).moveToElement(canvas, 0, 0).moveByOffset(849,341).click();`

[image]

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0);
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement canvas = driver.findElements(By.tagName("canvas")).get(0);
System.out.println(canvas.getSize().width/2); // -> returns 849
System.out.println(canvas.getSize().height/2); // -> returns 341
```

The problem is, the specific position isn't clicked and I don't know where is clicked just by using the code above. I've used Page Ruler to locate pointer but it didn't work in this situaion.

I'm hoping there is a solution which will highlight or show the location of pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the given HTML:

[image: html]

The desired `<canvas>` element is within is within a [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the *visibilityOfElementLocated* as follows:
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(Util.setup.driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("div.dialogMaster")));
  WebElement canvas = new WebDriverWait(Util.setup.driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName("canvas"))).get(0);
  System.out.println(canvas.getSize().width/2); // -> returns 849
  System.out.println(canvas.getSize().height/2); // -> returns 341
  ```

Comment: I forgot to add finding iframe code. Please check the updated code

Comment: Thank you, this one works. However, I want to know where is clicked. I used this code to see if the specifil location on canvas is clicked but no idea where is clicked: Actions action = new Actions(driver).moveToElement(canvas, 0, 0).moveByOffset(849,341).click();

Comment: As you are using `moveByOffset(849,341)` ofcoarse the click happens at that offset with respect to the upper-left corner of the canvas having the coordinates `(0,0)`. See [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923053/7429447).