# How to "send keys" to a canvas element for longer duration?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, canvas, keyboard-python

**My aim:**

I am trying to make a python bot to win [chrome's dino game](https://chromedino.com/).

The game allows 2 types of jumps:

- short jumps
- long jumps

Using `main_body.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)` (as shown in the code below) gives short jumps.

**My problem:**

*I am having difficulty executing long jumps.*

**My approach:**

Currently, for long jumps, I am using the `Keyboard` library:

`keyboard.press(keyboard.KEY_UP)`

This, unfortunately, requires the browser windows to be in focus all the time. Later on, I wish to run this program headlessly, so this approach won't work.

**Alternatively:**

I tried `ActionChains`:

```py
ActionChains(driver) \
.key_down(Keys.SPACE) \
.pause(0.2) \
.key_up(Keys.SPACE) \
.perform()
```

But this ends up scrolling the entire page. And doesn't fulfill the intended purpose.

*I simply wish to "send" these actions to the canvas element directly instead of performing them on the entire page...*

**I wish to do something like this**:

```
main_body.key_down(Keys.SPACE) 
time.sleep(0.2)
main_body.key_up(Keys.SPACE)
```

Although this will, of course, give me this error: `AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'key_down'` because `canvas` has no attribute `key_down` or `key_up`.

Here is an MCVE:

**NOTE**:
*In the code, the dino will keep jumping continuously but that is not the point, this is just to check the hights of the jumps and not to win the game.*

```py
import keyboard
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://chromedino.com/')
canvas = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.runner-canvas')
main_body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html")

try:
    canvas.click()
except:
    main_body.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)    


while True:
    #short jump
    main_body.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)

    #long jump
    ActionChains(driver) \
    .key_down(Keys.SPACE) \
    .pause(0.2) \
    .key_up(Keys.SPACE) \
    .perform()

    #long jump using keyboard:
    keyboard.press(keyboard.KEY_UP)
```

**Please see the effect of each type of jump by commenting out the code for others.**

If possible suggest some other alternative way of getting a long jump without using `Keyboard` and without scrolling the entire page...

Comment: Using `ActionChains` wouldn't scroll the entire page.Works fine on my PC.(I am using `Chrome`)

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA oh. I am using firefox. Let me give it a shot in chrome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot see a reproducible behaviour for jumps in that game. When i press UP o SPACE, I randomly see short or long jumps, so I cannot be really sure if my approach will work for you.

However, I think that, with a small effort, you could create a suitable event that will fit you needs.
Basically, since Selenium can execute arbitrary javascript, my approach here is to send a keydown event to the canvas element (tested with Firefox 77).

A screenshot is made for each iteration to ensure the dino actually jumps.

Have fun.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://chromedino.com/')

canvas = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.runner-canvas')
main_body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html")

try:
    canvas.click()
except:
    main_body.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)

while True:
    driver.execute_script('''
    var keydownEvt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        altKey:false,
        altKey: false,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelBubble: false,
        cancelable: true,
        charCode: 0,
        code: "Space",
        composed: true,
        ctrlKey: false,
        currentTarget: null,
        defaultPrevented: true,
        detail: 0,
        eventPhase: 0,
        isComposing: false,
        isTrusted: true,
        key: " ",
        keyCode: 32,
        location: 0,
        metaKey: false,
        repeat: false,
        returnValue: false,
        shiftKey: false,
        type: "keydown",
        which: 32,
    });
    arguments[0].dispatchEvent(keydownEvt);
    ''', canvas)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('proof_%s.png' % int(time.time()))
    time.sleep(0.2)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your assessment that you `randomly see short or long jumps` is correct. I too noticed this too while trying out @jizhihaoSAMA 's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501219/how-to-send-keys-to-a-canvas-element-for-longer-duration#comment111374719_62501219)... Your code is working correctly too. Can you please explain why you set the arguments in `new KeyboardEvent` to be what the are..? Also, you seem to have repeated `altKey:false` twice.

Comment: In order to obtain a valid event, I just added a keydown event to a random element in firefox console, and then attached a function that dumped that event. The duplication of "altKey" is surely a copy-paste refuse. Maybe you don't need every property of that event, you could try yourself and check against the target browser you wanto to use.

Answer (score 3):

You were so close. However a few words:

- The *T-RexDinosaur* within [T-Rex Chrome Dino Game](https://chromedino.com/) only animates within the [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas)
- The control, i.e. pressing the <kbd>space</kbd> bar doesn't needs to be sent within the [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409984/how-to-perform-mouse-wheel-scrolling-over-html5-canvas-in-selenium/53608731#53608731) but only can be initiated from the keyboard.

[image: T-RexDino]

- In your code block for **short jumps** you don't need to send `Keys.SPACE` to any element.
- In your code block for **long jumps** as well you don't need to send `Keys.SPACE` to any element and the variable `keyboard` wasn't defined as well.

---

### Solution

As a solution once you open the url you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` of the [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918530/how-to-find-the-coordinates-of-the-buttons-on-a-canvas-and-click-on-them-after/59923053#59923053) element and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) based solutions.

---

### Short Jumps

For short jumps you can use:

```
driver.get("https://chromedino.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "canvas.runner-canvas")))
while True:
    #short jump
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```

I was consistently able to score **69-72**

Snapshot:

[image: shortjump]

---

### Long Jumps with 0.2 seconds pause

For long jumps with `pause(0.2)` you can use:

```
driver.get("https://chromedino.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "canvas.runner-canvas")))
while True:
    #short jump
    # ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()

    #long jump
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).pause(0.2).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```

I was consistently able to score **65**

Snapshot:

[image: longjump_0.2]

---

### Long Jumps with 0.5 seconds pause

For long jumps with `pause(0.5)` you can use:

```
driver.get("https://chromedino.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "canvas.runner-canvas")))
while True:
    #short jump
    # ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()

    #long jump
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).pause(0.5).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```

I was consistently able to score **57-60**

Snapshot:

[image: longjump_0.5]

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution to it -

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('space', 'space', 'space')
```

It worked when i tried so should work. You can increase and decrease the number of time `'space'` has been written to increase the time duration or decrease it.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: I can't use `keyboard`. I want to run this program headless. So no browser window will be open...

Comment: I think you still will be able to use. Also can you explain what you mean by headless

Comment: When you normally open selenium, it opens a browser on your device (firefox, chrome, etc). In headless mode, you are opening the browser in the background. You can't directly interact with it as you normally would. No browser will actually pop open.