# Cannot locate an element inside of an map marker container / clicking to a red dot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i was wondering if it is possible to locate an element inside of an map marker container. If i go over it by inspecting it it returns me something like this and i cannot access inside of it.

```
<div id="map_markerContainer" style="position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 1001; height: 100%;"></div>
```

I would like to be able to click the red dot in the picture, i couldn't find any solutions.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: looks to be in canvas, can you share that HTML in text format here ? Is URL public ?

Comment: I am sorry the link is not available to public, that is why i deleted some parts from the picture. If there is any way you could give me, i would really appreciate it.@cruisepandey

Comment: what do you mean ` the link is available to public,` ? is there a typo ? if yes then can you share HTML in text format here

Comment: Yeah there was a typo, i edited it.

Comment: Is it located inside a canvas?

Comment: Yes, the red dot is located inside of a canvas. All i need to do is click to it but i couldn't figure out a way for now. @vitaliis

Comment: This changes everything

Comment: I am actually not sure if it is canvas or not, it is like a map, i cannot inspect it any further. I can move it click to a place, zoom in, zoom out etc. @vitaliis

Comment: There should be html element called `canvas`

Comment: Yes i just found it. 

<canvas id="73A67B51-81B1-54CF-D5AA-73E3451FC539" width="1919" height="832" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: transparent; z-index: 1000;"></canvas>

I think this is what you mean. @vitaliis

Comment: yes can you share bit more HTML, in and around of that `canvas` ?

Comment: Sure, here is it with a picture. [link](https://imgur.com/a/c4e2qSW)

Comment: Check here, when I answered this, I spent a lot of time guessing it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185265/click-on-generated-button-with-seleniumjava/67186591#67186591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with pyautogui and Opencv in this case. What you would do is snip a screen shot of the area you would want to click then you would tell pyautogui to use Opencv to take a full screenshot and scan it for the snip you took. Then you would have pyautogui move the mouse to the screen shot and click it or you can just have it print out when you have found it.

Example

```
 login = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Login.png', confidence=0.9)
    time.sleep(5)
    if login != None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(login)
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click()
```