# How to move an internal HTML scrollbar using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Selenium + Python to scrape this [site](https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiYjJjOGQyZjItM2FkMS00OGRjLTg4M2MtZDQxNjNhNmUyZDhmIiwidCI6IjczZDYxNzk5LWMyODQtNDAyMi04ZDQxLTU0Y2M0ZjE5MjllZiJ9). I am interested in getting the information out of the Power BI table, which I can currently do using Beautiful Soup. My problem is that only the cells that are currently in view are loaded on the page. The rest are loaded as the table is scrolled, which can only be done if the mouse is over the table (in other words, this `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', target)` doesn't work) or if the scroll bar is dragged downward. The code I am currently using tries to find the scrollBar element, click-and-hold, and drag it down some number of pixels to load another set of cells.

```
scrollBar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("scroll-bar-part-bar")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(scrollBar).click_and_hold(scrollBar).move_by_offset(0,30).release().perform()
```

It kinda seems like the "mouse" isn't in the correct place when it clicks and holds. Is there a more straight forward was of doing this? I have tried simulating a mouse wheel scroll from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274852/mouse-scroll-wheel-with-selenium-webdriver-on-element-without-scrollbar) answer, but I am not able to get that to work either.

Comment: Hey Can You Please share the Complete code you are using to scrape data from that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments.scrollBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight)",scrollBar)
```

This scrolls the element, you should do scroll on the scroll bar element